# jQuery.Cycle - use two different effects on same container

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-cycle, jquery-effects

I'm currently using ***jQuery.Cycle*** to cycle through a few child `<div>` tags. However, I want the default cycle fx to be `fade`, and when I click on the `next` or `prev` selectors, I want the cycle fx to temporarily change to `scrollRight` or `scrollLeft` depending on the selector clicked.

*Is this possible?*

jQuery code, if necessary:

```
$('#banner_content').cycle({
    fx: 'fade', // choose your transition type, ex: fade, scrollUp, shuffle, etc...
    timeout: 6500,
    speed: 2000,
    next: $("#right_arrow a"),
    prev: $("#left_arrow a"),
});
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ok, I added my question on the [jQuery Forum](http://forum.jquery.com), and the creator responded with the following [answer](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-cycle-different-effects-on-same-cycle#14737000001121790).

Here is my code that I developed for this:

```
var slideIndex = 0;
var nextIndex = 0;
var prevIndex = 0;

$('#banner_content').cycle({
    fx: 'fade',//fx: 'scrollHorz', // choose your transition type, ex: fade, scrollUp, shuffle, etc...
    timeout: 8000,
    speed: 1000,
    easingIn:20,
    easingOut:40,
    after: function(currSlideElement, nextSlideElement, options) {
        slideIndex = options.currSlide;
        nextIndex = slideIndex + 1;
        prevIndex = slideIndex -1;

        if (slideIndex == options.slideCount-1) {
            nextIndex = 0;
        }

        if (slideIndex == 0) {
            prevIndex = options.slideCount-1;
        }
    }
}); 

$("div.left_arrow a").click(function () {
    $('#banner_content').cycle(nextIndex, "scrollRight");
});

$("div.right_arrow a").click(function () {
    $('#banner_content').cycle(prevIndex, "scrollLeft");
});
```